# Get google contacts after successful signin in swift

Tags: json, swift, contacts, nsurlrequest, google-contacts-api

I am using the following code to have my user successfully sign into their goole account from my swift app but I am not able to retrieve contacts after. What am I doing wrong? The JSON response says There was an error in your request.Thats all we know

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    //
    let idToken = user.authentication.idToken
    self.getUserContacts(email: user!.profile.email!)
}


func getUserContacts(email : String){
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/\(email)/full")!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 120.0
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        let result = self.convertDataToDictionary(data: data!)

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are force unwrapping a ton of stuff(not recommended). I would break down the requestURL first and then go from there. Create a string(and unwrap it) for 'GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.accessToken' first and make sure it is what you expect. It's possible "optional" was attached to it somewhere when you force unwrapped. If the problems persist, please specify the exact line where you get an error response and show full JSON code.

Comment: I have updated the code but the new version still returns the bad status. Also it isn't a code error, per say. Google is returning an error in the response

Comment: I don't see any updates / you showing what each line prints in the debugger during run time(for instance print user!.profile.email!).  Like I said, you need to unwrap and remove any ! in the code, especially regarding the info you need for the URL.  We can't isolate if it is a code string error or google error until you do that.

Comment: I replaced the code in general above. this is where it is hitting po URL(string: "http://google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/\(email)/full")!
▿ http://google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/lmyemail@gmail.com/full

Comment: and this is the legible part of the response </style></head>\n<body><a href=\"//www.google.com/\" id=\"g\"><img src=\"//www.google.com/images/logo_sm_2.gif\" alt=\"Google\" width=\"150\" height=\"55\"></a>\n<p><b>401.</b>\n<ins>That&#39;s an error.</ins></p>\n<p>There was an error in your request.\n<ins>That&#39;s all we know.</ins></p></body></html>

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue as well, and I found the way to fix it

```
func doLoginGoogle() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = ["https://www.google.com/m8/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"];
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}


func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    let urlString = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=\(user.authentication.accessToken!)"

    print(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes)

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get)
        .responseString { (data) in
            print(data)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error is "Unauthorized", which means either that you didn't include credentials or that the credentials are bad.  In this case, it appears to be the former.

You need to do something with that OAuth token.  I'm not sure exactly what, because I don't know that particular Google API, but I suspect that you're supposed to be inserting it into some header field in subsequent requests, e.g.

```
request.addValue("Bearer " + idToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

or similar.  Look in the documentation for that API and see what you're actually supposed to do with that token.  The above is a pure guess.  :-)